# Phalcon 3.4.0 does not bootstrap with PHP 5.6.33-0+deb8u1

Tags: php, nginx, phalcon, php-5.6

502 Bad Gateway on loading the page with PHP 5.6 but it loads with PHP 7.3, It returns 502 bad gateway on this line **echo $application->handle()->getContent()**

**PHP Version : 5.6.33-0+deb8u1**

**Loaded Phalcon : 3.4.0**

**NGINX Configuration**

```
location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args;
        disable_symlinks off;
   }

   location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
       # With php5-fpm:
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_index /index.php;
       fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
   }
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

try {

    //Register an autoloader
    $loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

    $loader->registerDirs(array(
        APPLICATION_CONTROLLERS,
        APPLICATION_MODELS,
        APPLICATION_CORE,
        APPLICATION_PHALCON_INCUBATOR,
        APPLICATION_LISTENERS,
        APPLICATION_TRAITS
    ))->register();

    $loader->registerNamespaces(array(
        'Erp\Backend\Models' => APPLICATION_MODELS,
        'Erp\Backend\Core' => APPLICATION_CORE,
        'Erp\Backend\Validators' => APPLICATION_VALIDATORS,
        'Phalcon' => APPLICATION_PHALCON_INCUBATOR,
        'Erp\Backend\Listeners' => APPLICATION_LISTENERS,
        'Erp\Backend\Traits' => APPLICATION_TRAITS
    ), true);


    //Create a DI
    $di = new Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();

    $di->set('dispatcher', function () use ($di) {
        $dispatcher = new Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher();
        return $dispatcher;
    });


    //Setup the view component
    $di->set('view', function () {
        $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
        $view->setViewsDir('../application/views/');

        return $view;
    });

    //Handle the request
    $application = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Application($di);
    echo $application->handle()->getContent();

} catch (\Phalcon\Exception $e) {
    echo 'PhalconException: ', $e->getMessage();
}
```

Couldn't figure out what's going wrong. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Does it support PHP5?

Comment: @kerbholz https://docs.phalcon.io/3.4/en/installation#software PHP >= 5.5 is supported